# What is the proper close reason for developer center (Store) based questions

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

First thing, I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175701/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic-for-stack-over) thread to confirm my belief that developer-centric questions are off topic.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986474/apple-app-store-how-do-i-make-my-application-available-to-new-yorkers-only) question which is not a specific programming question, and as per my understanding, should be off topic on stackoverflow.

So, I tried to vote this question, but stopped midway because I got confused when choosing a specific vote close reason.

1. duplicate of  - **not applicable**
2. unclear what you're asking - **not applicable, question is perfectly
   clear**
3. too broad - **not applicable**
4. primarly opinion based - **not applicable**
5. off topic because  - **Surely, but what is the reason**

   - *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic    for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools
     used primarily    for programming. You may be able to get help on
     Super User.*

     **No this is not a super user question.**
   - *Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe    the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce
     it. See    SSCCE.org for guidance.*

     **Not Applicable.**
   - *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of    the problem being solved. Include attempted
     solutions, why they    didn't work, and the expected results. See
     also: Stack Overflow    question checklist.*

     **Not applicable.**
   - *Questions on professional server, networking, or related    infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow
     unless    they directly involve programming or programming tools.
     You may be    able to get help on Server Fault.*

     **This tells about server fault kind of questions, right? Not sure about this one**
   - *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite    off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as
     they tend to    attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead,
     describe the problem    and what has been done so far to solve it.*

     **Not applicable.**
   - *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*

     **Not applicable, none of the site listed will take this question.**
   - Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

     **Does choosing this reason, takes it directly to moderators? I kind of remember reading like that somewhere.**

Which is the proper methods to close questions like the one I mentioned above?

Comment: maybe something with the custom closing reason: "not programming related; it's about application distribution"

Comment: Custom *flags* go direct to mods; custom *close reasons* (what you've got here) are just normal close votes.

Comment: @michaelb958 thanks. I got it wrong then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986474/apple-app-store-how-do-i-make-my-application-available-to-new-yorkers-only?noredirect=1) is closed now with a custom closing reason. And the custom close reason is

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App store
>   usage, which have been deemed off topic on StackOverflow

which is specific to the question and easy to understand. I checked back on the question today to see it already has 4 close votes. I added the 5th vote.

Answer (score 2):

Why have you made the assumption that it should be closed? If the question was retitled to be *How can I restrict which regions can download my app from the store?*, would you consider that on topic?

You will get questions that are borderline, and I would consider this one of them. It's not too localized (which isn't a valid close reason anymore) as other people are likely to want to know the answer. It's about packaging and distribution of the app, so it's not really off topic.

A good rule of thumb is: if you're not sure, don't touch it. There is a whole community out there, if you can't make up your mind then let them decide.

Comment: *A good rule of thumb is: if you're not sure, don't touch it* - I know that, Thats why I didn't close vote because I got confused, and the question still there with 0 down votes and 0 close votes. But I will have to know what I should do if I get a similar question in future.

Comment: *It's about packaging and distribution of the app, so it's not really off topic* Disagree with you that though, I can understand how packaging of an app can be on topic, but distribution is out of the perimeter of stackoverflow. And this question is only about distribution.

Comment: *If the question was retitled to be How can I restrict which regions can download my app from the store?, would you consider that on topic?* - NO, as per my understanding of stackoverflow rules on questions

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Like I said, it's a borderline question. You could always type a custom close reason and maybe the rest of the community will agree with you, if they don't then your close vote will eventually expire.